# CakePHP FormHelper::input – set Index

Tags: arrays, forms, cakephp, input

I want to create a Form with CakePHP's FormHelper having a `count` fields for multiple items. My form looks like this:

```
| name                   | count |
|------------------------+-------|
| Item #1                |     2 |
| Item #2                |     0 |
| Item #3                |    15 |
| Item #4                |     1 |
```

**What I need** is a Form that submits data having the following structure:

```
array(
    'Order' => array(
        '0' => array(
            'id' => 1
            'count' => 2
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'id' => 2
            'count' => 0
        ),
        '2' => array(
            'id' => 3
            'count' => 15
        ),
        '3' => array(
            'id' => 4
            'count' => 1
        )
    )
)
```

**What I tried** is this (within my Order view and ONLY the inputs, no table or layout!):

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Order');
foreach ($item as $value) {
    echo $this->Form->input('count', array('type' => 'number', 'min' => '0');
}
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

**What I get** is an array formed like this:

```
array(
    'Order' => array(
        'count' => '1'
    )
)
```

Comment: You need to use Order.{n}.count syntax. Otherwise you end up with multiple times the same form field.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you'd do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont, but the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions